# How to use getElementsByClassName instead of getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use this JS but with a class and ID. Is this possible?

```
 document.getElementsById('container').style.marginLeft = '350px';
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('container').style.marginLeft = '350px';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: You need to have loop

Comment: No, this is the solution .querySelector. Why do i need a loop?

Comment: getElementsByClassName will give you a collection of class name as `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].style.marginLeft = '350px';
```

And so does this which i think is better for my specific situation :

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById('side').style.width = '350px';
    document.querySelector('.container').style.marginLeft = '350px';
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.container {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="side" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>

     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that getElementsByClassName is not available in IE8 and below

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('.container').style.marginLeft = '350px';
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background: #000; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: Is that the only way to code style.marginLeft in jQuery?

Comment: $("div.container").css({'margin-left':'350px'});

Comment: How do i write this in jQuery  document.getElementById('side-widget').style.width = '350px';

Comment: $("#side-widget").css({'width':'350px'});

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection/array. So all you have to do it append the index number.

`document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0]` gets the first one.

Comment: Yes but i already included that solution and i think .querySelector is a better solution in this specific case.